# Wait for data to be returned from database - ajax and Express

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I think I'm close to getting this working, just missing something simple or I've setup my database query function incorrectly. At the moment I get no data returned as a Promise is still pending, though it does log out in the console.

index.js

```
async function leagueFixtures(league_name){
  var data = await queries.league_fixtures(league_name);
  return data;
}


app.post('/league_fixtures', function (req, res) {
  var league_name = req.body.league_name;
  const fixtures = leagueFixtures(league_name); // also tried await leagueFixtures(league_name) here but get a syntax error
  console.log(fixtures);
  res.json({success: true, data: fixtures })
});
```

Ajax request

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/league_fixtures',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: "json",
  data: { league_name: league_name },
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
    alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
  }
})
```

Where am I going wrong and what I have misunderstood?

Comment: @RolandStarke you don ' t seem to calling the function getFixtures at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> make the express request handler async function   like the following

```
  app.post('/league_fixtures', async function (req, res) {
      try {
          var league_name = req.body.league_name;
          const fixtures = await leagueFixtures(league_name); 
          console.log(fixtures);
          res.json({success: true, data: fixtures })

     } catch(err){
      // do your error handling here
       res.status(500).send({ error: 'Something failed!' })
     }

    });
```

Comment: Thank you, thats worked, knew it would be something simple